# Variable is not used in my zookeeper systemd service

Tags: linux, apache-zookeeper, jmx-exporter

I wanted to use Prometheus JMX exporter for Apache Zookeeper which was installed from Kafka package installation. I did according https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/jmx-exporter/ so I use variable EXTRA_ARGS (+ I also set variable to /etc/enviroment):

```
export EXTRA_ARGS="-javaagent:/opt/jmx-exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar=7070:/opt/jmx-exporter/zookeeper.yaml"
```

If I start zookeeper by command bellow I can see server listen on port 7070:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
```

But when I tried to start zookeeper by systemd service server does not listen on port 7070. ExecStart is same as command which I started manually from command line.

```
[Unit]
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Does anybody know what I do wrong and how to set properly?

Thanks, Roman

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Environment="SERVER_JVMFLAGS=-javaagent:/opt/jmx-exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar=7070:/opt/jmx-exporter/zookeeper.yaml"
```

Comment: I added 
Environment="KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/opt/kafka/prom-jmx-agent/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.16.1.jar=7071:/opt/kafka/prom-jmx-agent/kafka-2_0_0.yml"
which works for me.